# Why Islam is not all over the world?

Tags: allah, jahannam

As I know, islam says the other religious followers will be sent to hell.

But my simple question is, there are many people around the world (from Amazon forest, etc..) who even doesn't know who Allah is and what islam is. So if they are also sent to hell then that's not fair. Could you please someone explain to me on this.

As I heard islam says Allah has done everything on or for a purpose. So what's the purpose of creating some people in a forest (where even they don't know what islam or who Allah is), and at the end they are sent to hell, just because they follow some other god defined by their tribes?

Comment: They were created to worship Allah by at first realizing that He created everything.

Comment: @Medi1Saif How do they worship without knowing Allah is there?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/1244

Comment: @Loading... so it seems though Allah is the creater of the world he accepts that he is unable to share Islam with all people of the world.

Comment: What Allah does is not a limitation on what He *can* do. It is not binding on Allah  to share Islam with everyone, and He has a way to test and judge the Ahl al-Fatrah.

Comment: @Explorer it’s not that Allah can’t it’s just that if Allah did intervene would it really be a test for us if we have 100% confirmation of Gods existence. Believing in the unseen and putting our faith in God is what we have to do. Those who won’t get the chance on earth will get there chance after or else it is not fair just to send someone to Hell for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Islam is sent for the whole humanity,

> And We have not sent you, [O Muhammad], except as a mercy to the worlds. (Al-Anbya 21:107, https://quran.com/21/107)
>
> ... Every Prophet used to be sent to his nation only but I have been sent to all mankind. (Sahih Bukhari, https://sunnah.com/bukhari/7)

What about other people that you think never heard about Islam? They were sent messengers too

> Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another. **And never would We punish until We sent a messenger**. (Al-Isra 17:15, https://quran.com/17/15)
>
> And We did not send any messenger except [speaking] in the language of his people to state clearly for them, and Allah sends astray [thereby] whom He wills and guides whom He wills. And He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise. (Ibrahim 14:4, https://quran.com/14/4)

Are those messengers Muslims? Yes they are Muslims (one who submits themselves to Allah)

If those forest people dont follow their messenger(s) then they are astrayed

Will they go to hell? only Allah knows because the rulings through their messenger with the rulings through Muhammad maybe different

Comment: how do these quotes answer my question. Please elaborate

Comment: @Explorer I've edited the answer

Comment: so people living in Amazon won't be punished for praying some other god as the messanger is not yet sent to them, is that what you meant?

Comment: from islamic perspective, all those messengers preach people to worship one God (Allah) and if they don't they are astrayed. Just look at the current christianity and hinduism, their scripture is actually telling them to worship one God but the people dont,

Comment: you didin't answer my queation yet. I'm not asking about christians or hindus.., I'm asking about the people who still doesn't know about Allah or Islam, and how they get treated after death

Comment: @Explorer Thats already clear, if those people don't follow their messenger(s) then they are astrayed (the messenger here is not Muhammad, since you assume they never heard anything about Muhammad). Will they go to hell? only Allah knows because the rulings through their messenger with the rulings through Muhammad maybe different.

Comment: @Explorer As per Islam, all nations & tribes (including those in the Amazon) have had messengers sent to them in the past. How many of them believed and how many of them rejected is a matter of Unseen for us today.

Answer (score 0):

First of all how did you know that these parts of the world have no Muslims ? or at leas some that knows about Islam ? (you are just assuming without any facts) especially that today communication methods are easily and in everyone's hand.

Second, ALLAH will only ask people who received Islam in a way or another and didn't believe, the ones who didn't reach Islam by any mean or Islam reached them but not correct and deformed by any mean wither will be tested in judgment day or it is said that they will not be punished according to many scholars such as (Al-Ghazali). 
This was taken according to these two verses:

> **Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another. And never would We punish until We sent a messenger. (Surt Israa - 15)**
>
> مَّنِ اهْتَدَىٰ فَإِنَّمَا يَهْتَدِي لِنَفْسِهِ ۖ وَمَن ضَلَّ فَإِنَّمَا يَضِلُّ عَلَيْهَا ۚ وَلَا تَزِرُ وَازِرَةٌ وِزْرَ أُخْرَىٰ ۗ وَمَا كُنَّا مُعَذِّبِينَ حَتَّىٰ نَبْعَثَ رَسُولًا
>    (15 الاسراء )

> **It almost bursts with rage. Every time a company is thrown into it, its keepers ask them, "Did there not come to you a warner?"
>   [8] They will say," Yes, a warner had come to us, but we denied and said, ' Allah has not sent down anything. You are not but in great error.' "
>    [9]** (surt Al-Mulk 8-9)
>
> كُلَّمَا أُلْقِيَ فِيهَا فَوْجٌ سَأَلَهُمْ خَزَنَتُهَا أَلَمْ يَأْتِكُمْ نَذِيرٌ . قالُوا بَلَى قَدْ جَاءَنَا نَذِيرٌ فَكَذَّبْنَا  (سورة الملك : 8،9).

Third don't forget that, ALLAH said:

> وَلَوْ شَاء رَبُّكَ لآمَنَ مَن فِي الأَرْضِ كُلُّهُمْ جَمِيعاً أَفَأَنتَ تُكْرِهُ النَّاسَ حَتَّى يَكُونُوا مُؤْمِنِينَ
>   (سورة يونس - 99)
>
> **And had your Lord willed, those on earth would have believed - all of them entirely. Then, [O Muhammad], would you compel the people in order that they become believers?**

So, the purpose is ALLAH's will and these are his creatures, and that is enough.

Comment: The communication is good today, not 100 years ago, people die 100 years ago too. And its very clear that those tribes in Amazon haven’t met any messanger, and I personally know some of similar kind of tribes in other asian countries, they don’t even heard the word islam or Allah.

Comment: my answer includes people who lived in 100 years ago and people who lived now, and people who had no messenger, and people who had, and people who received Islam by some way, and people who didn't receive Islam or received it deformed.

Comment: Ok, So I'm not a muslim. I haven't heard the message from the messenger yet. So I hope I will be excluded from the list.

Comment: so you are trying to find a way to not be questioned about no being Muslim ? you Ignore that I said (received Islam in a way or another) .. and apparently you received it and know about it because you are chatting with me about it .. so you will be questioned about it

Comment: So are you a messanger?

Comment: who said anything about receiving Islam form a messenger  (prophet) is a must ? a messenger in the verse I mentioned might be the prophet him self or someone else who knew the prophet or someone who heard about it from someone who knew the prophet until it reached us .... and no I am not a messenger

Comment: So what's the point of being a muslim? Is it just to get the decision by Allah after we dead, whether to go to hell or heaven?

Comment: so you believe that there is a god and his name  ALLAH ?

Comment: Nope, I don't know that there's a god called Allah. I was referring to your belief.

Comment: OK, so Islam is the rituals that sent by a god called ALLAH to a prophet called Muhammed and he is the last prophet and The Quran is ALLAH's revelation to Muhammed, and we must obey ALLAH and Muhammed  and do what the Quran say. we Mulsim believe it is the true religion, and ALLAH is the only god and he is the almighty and powerful and all of this  world is his creation, and so we must obey him.

Comment: now you know, so you can look more about it, and see yourself what is actually says , and choose to believe or not

Comment: Thanks for the information. But it seems like I should not bother Allah after my death. Because since I don't know about islam yet and I don't believe things just because someone says something. So I will stay out of those beliefs. Thanks again. But still my question `why the messangers are not sent to every where` is still not answered. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: to answer this question you need to agree first that ALLAH is the only creator, and Muhammed is his messenger and the last of prophets sent to humanity, then you will find your answer, you want to go to the end of the book and understand the story , in any case you now know about Islam and Islam reached you

Comment: Is that the Allahs way? By saying now you know the Islam, just commenting on a website? I hope this is not what he meant. Are you trying to force me to accept Islam, or are you trying to scare me by saying, now my fate is in Allah's hand?

Comment: I didn't say all of what you are accusing me of, I said now you know that there is a religion  called Islam and god called ALLAH, and later you can go and read and educate yourself about it and seek truth. and dear no, we don't force anyone to Islam, in my comments above I told you (choose to believe or not) .. you came here and asked for an answer and a truth, and these two both needs a will and power, so take your time and don't go into conclusions quickly

Comment: Thanks for that answer, the contradiction is on, `"to get answer first I need to agree that ALLAH is the creator"` that's from the above comment made by you. That makes me to think no point of learning Islam. Because first we should understand / realize the truth. Then only the acceptance should happen. Here ISLAM seems the other way round, which is not gonna work for me. Thanks again..!

Comment: go through the way you like it, I hope you reach the truth